# Android animation sometimes skipping scaling

Tags: android

I have the following animation xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- 1.42 is a little more than sqrt(2), which covers the diagonal -->
    <scale android:toXScale="142%"
           android:toYScale="142%"
           android:pivotX="50%"
           android:pivotY="50%"
           android:duration="0" />
    <rotate
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="45"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:duration="0" />
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0%p"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%p"
        android:duration="150" />
</set>
```

I use it to cover one square view with another, making for a diagonal transition. The problem is that sometimes the only the rotate and translate elements will be applied, sliding over a view that has not been enlarged. It will only happen around 20% of the time - any idea why?

Comment: try using android:fillAfter="true" inside <set > tag

Comment: That does not help. I think there is a problem with the scale part, since both translate and rotate are running properly.

Comment: Do you want that after animation ends the view remains enlarged??? because i run this code and it is scaling every time but after animation ends it return to it original position

Comment: I'm replacing the Views after the animation ends so that is not the problem.  I think the problem is I'm chaining a set of animations together - I'm showing a transition across several views one after another (triggered in onAnimatioEnd) and this is the final animation. Again, it works properly most of the time but every now and again, you can see the view rotated and sliding, but not scaled. Could this be a bug in Android?

Comment: In my lolipop its working fine , I would recommend you to test your app on different mobiles with different API to know weather its a bug in your code or android